# How do I remove pooled paint on walls?

Tags: drywall, paint, repainting

I am renovating my first home and noticed in several rooms there are areas of what appear to be pooled paint. To me, it looks like someone applied too much paint and did not smooth it out before it dried. Here are some pictures:

[image: pooled paint near ceiling]

[image: pooled paint under window]

I mainly noticed these closer to the ceiling.

Is this really just paint, or is it something else? What should I do before I repaint the walls to ensure this isn't visible and the wall is smooth? Is it enough to just sand down the "pooled" areas?

Comment: There's a word for those.  That is called a **"run"**.  If you talk to any paint person and say your paint has runs, they'll grok. It's from painting the paint too thick, probably from letting it get too thick in the roller tray or not following the instructions on your paint sprayer.

Comment: Thanks! Is there anything specific I should do to remove the runs before repainting? Do I just need to sand it down?

Comment: ligthly sanding it would be great - if it is very thick i would lightly scrape it. The important thing is to et a more even transition which is small enough for the new paint to cover it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you gently sand it down and feather it out. Then you need to paint it. Do not oversand it as it will then show through the new paint.

Comment: Depending how thick the paint is, a light skim coat may help too.